# Keeping a counter for execution of java application

Tags: java

Here is the scenario:

I am running a Java Application which makes a call to REST interface, and gets back some states of variables as integers (Basically LAST Successful Build # form Teamcity)

Now, since i am running the utility from Jenkins, i want to compare the LastSuccessfulBuild Number between two REST Calls. What is the Best way to do this ? Here is what i have in terms of code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class LastSuccessBuildNum {

    private  final static String getDateTime()
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        return df.format(new Date());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            Client client = Client.create();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            File f = File.createTempFile("default", ".properties");

            properties.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));

            String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");


            String username = properties.getProperty("username");

            String pass = properties.getProperty("password");
            //System.out.println(pass);
            String buildNumber = properties.getProperty("buildNumber");


            client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("username", "password"));

            WebResource webResource = client
                    .resource("http://a.b.c.d/teamcity/app/rest/buildTypes/id:bt26/builds/status:SUCCESS/number");
            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("text/plain").get(
                    ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            /**
             * Prepend timestamp to latestBuildNum
             */

            System.out.println(getDateTime());
            String latestBuildNum_1 = response.getEntity(String.class);

            //System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

            /** 
             * Save latest build number to a local file
             */
            //System.out.println(latestBuildNum);

            String datelbn = (getDateTime() + "-" + latestBuildNum_1);
            //System.out.println(datelbn);
            //If latestBuildNumberLocal < latestBuildNum, then save to file latestBuildNum
            // Else do nothing
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("PreMDNSlatestSuccBuildNum.txt"), latestBuildNum_1);
            /**
             * Get Content from the file, which would be the LatestBuildNumber at LAST run.
             * SO the NEXT run, will save the number in a different file.
             * Then we compare the contents of these two files
             * using StringToInt() and compare
             */

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there more? You seem to be on the right track.

Comment: no more code, but how do i compare two integers in two files, and HOW do implement 2 files on a rotating basis with every run

Comment: Is there the possibility of multiple threads (or processes) attempting to read/write from these file concurrently, or is your application completely single-process / single-threaded? Also, do you need the contents of the file to be human-readable?

Comment: @noahz This is single threaded. The contents are human readable, since this is how they are received as integer. But the main function of this utility (all of which is provided above) is:

I am doing a REST Call, using a small Java Utility that i have written, to get the "Last Successful" Build Number from TeamCity.

I want to run this utility as a Jenkins Project every 2 hours, and compare consecutive run results , and IF the current Run Result number is higher, then 
"Build Other Projects" as a Post Build Task. So between runs, i would have to keep the counts / results in a file

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of what you want. There are many libraries out there to reduce the amount of "boilerplate" (Apache Commons IO, for example. Java 7 also consolidates the exception-handling and resource cleanup.

Also, there is more you could do to this code to make it "production ready" (it's just a sketch). For starters, we should use a logging library instead of STDOUT (`java.util.logging` at a minimum).

Finally, my example reads/writes a primitive int, but you should be able to read/write/parse Strings in much the same way.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class GetLatestBuildNumber {


    private static final AtomicInteger number = new AtomicInteger();
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "latest_build_number.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int latest = fetchLatestBuildNumber();
        writeLatestBuildNumber(latest);
        int next = fetchLatestBuildNumber();

        int previous;
        try {

            previous = readLatestBuildNumber();

            System.out.println("previous build number " + previous);
            System.out.println("current build number " + next);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("failed to read last build number " +
                        "from file " + FILE_NAME + ": " + ioe);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfx) {
            System.out.println("failed to parse last build number: " + nfx);
        }

    }

    private static int fetchLatestBuildNumber() {
       return number.getAndIncrement();
    }

    private static void writeLatestBuildNumber(int number) {

        int latestBuildNumber = fetchLatestBuildNumber();
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(FILE_NAME);
            writer.write(Integer.toString(latestBuildNumber));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("failed to write build number "
                        + number + ", error: " + ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (writer != null) writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* we tried... */ }
        }

    }

    private static int readLatestBuildNumber() throws IOException  {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
            String number = reader.readLine();
            return Integer.parseInt(number);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /* we tried. */ }

        }

    }
}
```